# Why BigQuery write is spending so much time in GCP Dataflow?

Tags: java, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have an Apache Beam streaming pipeline running in Google Cloud Dataflow the last step of the pipeline consist in streaming insert to a BigQuery table.

When I look at the pipeline in the Dataflow monitor, I notice that this particular step is taking a lot of time but the data seems to be correctly inserted into the table.

[image: BigQuery write step]

Comment: That time showing on the UI is an approx time for processing all the elements depending on the throughput of the pipeline

Comment: Beam support loading data and streaming data to big query. Streaming is faster than loading data.

Comment: Instead of using a job to load data into BigQuery, you can choose to stream your data into BigQuery one record at a time by using the tabledata.insertAll method. This approach enables querying data without the delay of running a load job.

Comment: Can you tell me what do you do in that block of code which is taking longer than usual?

Comment: @AlexandreMoraes yes, in first place i convert my object into TableRow and then perform a streaming insert.

Comment: @balamuruganv i'm using BigQueryIO.writeTableRows().withMethod( BigQueryIO.Write.Method.STREAMING_INSERTS ) is that the way you suggest?

Comment: @IgnacioNicolasNegroCaino, is the pipeline writing data to BigQuery or is it stuck ?Can you share your code? Also, how many workers are being used in the writing stage? Have you set them manually or let to Dataflow do it automatically? Moreover, do you see any warnings in the logs?

Comment: @AlexandreMoraes The data is not getting stuck, i don't see any warning, i have 1 worker at 2% of processing capacity set autamatically. My code looks like this:
BigQueryIO.writeTableRows().withMethod( BigQueryIO.Write.Method.STREAMING_INSERTS )

Comment: @IgnacioNicolasNegroCaino, would you mind sharing your code so I can investigate further? Also, can you describe more your process?